# Lubridate round_date() seems to change time zone when rounding to day

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I'm trying to round (to the day) date-time data. Here's what the data look like:

```
> date[10:15]
[1] "2016-08-31 23:03:02 EDT" "2016-08-31 22:52:50 EDT"
[3] "2016-08-31 22:50:02 EDT" "2016-08-31 22:34:28 EDT"
[5] "2016-08-31 22:31:41 EDT" "2016-08-31 22:25:37 EDT"
```

The problem is when I use the `lubridate` function `round_date()` to "round" the date to only the year, month, day parts, the date seems to have been changed to UTC (note: UTC is ~5 hours ahead of EDT, so `00:40:17 EDT` is `05:40:17 UTC`, if I'm understanding correctly):

```
> date_r
[1] "2016-09-01 EDT" "2016-09-01 EDT" "2016-09-01 EDT"
[4] "2016-09-01 EDT" "2016-09-01 EDT" "2016-09-01 EDT"
```

Here's a reprex:

```
structure(c(1472698982, 1472698370, 1472698202, 1472697268, 1472697101, 
1472696737), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/Detroit")

date_r <- round_date(date, unit = "day")
```

If the date contains `8-31` in EDT, I'm trying to have the rounded date be on `8-31` (not `9-1`). How can I retain the time zone when rounding the date? Open to non-`Lubridate` answers.

Comment: `format(d, "%Y-%m-%d")`

Comment: R Dates are always UTC. The print and format functions are make them local.

Comment: @d.b that works

Comment: @42- thanks but that does not seem to address how to round them for use, say, in a time series plot, where they need to be local?

Comment: Please try to read for meaning. If you understand that "rounding" to Date will be done at the the level of the internal representation the your results make sense and the 'format' function doesn't round but rather "floors".

Comment: Thanks, it was not apparent to me that that was what "rounding" (operating on level of the internal representation) does, nor was it that "flooring" (operating on the level of the formatted date?) does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `strptime` in base R

```
d = structure(c(1472698982, 1472698370, 1472698202, 1472697268, 1472697101, 
     1472696737), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/Detroit")

strptime(d, format = "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "America/Detroit")
#OR
#strptime(d, format = "%Y-%m-%d", tz = attr(d, "tzone"))
#[1] "2016-08-31 EDT" "2016-08-31 EDT" "2016-08-31 EDT"
#[4] "2016-08-31 EDT" "2016-08-31 EDT" "2016-08-31 EDT"
```

Or use `floor_date` of `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
floor_date(d, unit = "day")
#[1] "2016-08-31 EDT" "2016-08-31 EDT" "2016-08-31 EDT"
#[4] "2016-08-31 EDT" "2016-08-31 EDT" "2016-08-31 EDT"
```

Comment: thanks, `format(d, "%Y-%m-%d")` also seems to work fine, I think

Comment: @JoshuaRosenberg, I think the approach in the answer is better as the output is not a string

Comment: For what it is worth, for my case `floor_date()` returns a `POSIXct` type date and `striptime()` returns a `POSIXlt` type date (the `POSIXct` and `floor_date()` approach helped me to create my time series more easily - it looks like `dplyr::count()` treated the `POSIXlt` date type as a character, whereas the other remained a date (which was what I needed!).